# Using the jQuery validatation plugin to send multiple values to an ASP.NET MVC controller action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-plugins, jquery, jquery-validate

Using the [jQuery Validation](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) plugin and AJAX, how can I validate the contents of say an input (textbox) but pass more than one parameter to a controller action?

A brilliant example of passing a single value via AJAX using the plugin can be found [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/cibrax/archive/2008/08/01/combining-jquery-validation-with-asp-net-mvc.aspx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the code for jQuery Validation it looks like the post data can not be customized. So you'll have to stick with query parameters:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#form-sign-up").validate(
  {
    var param1 = $('#mytextbox').val();

    rules:
    {
        login:
        {
          required: true,
          remote: '<%=Url.Action("IsLoginAvailable", "Accounts") %>?param1=' + param1
        }
      }  
    });

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#form-sign-up").validate( {
    rules: {
      email: {
        required: true,
        email: true
      },
      surname: {
        required: true,
        surname: true
      }
    },
    messages: {
      email: {
        required: "Please provide an email",
        email: "Please provide a valid email"
      },
      surname: {
        required: "Please provide a surname",
        surname: "Please provide a valid surname"
      }
    }
  });
});
```

**edit** found a large demo [here](http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/)

Comment: The problem I have is that based on the user-name and the value of a hidden field goes into making a unique pair. So when validating the login name I need to pass both the login name and the hidden field value to an action. If you check the example in the question you'll see what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

The correct Script will be

remote: function() {
                    var p = $j('#productName').val();
                    return "../Product/LookupRevision?p=" + p;
                } 
instead of

remote: "../Product/LookupRevision"